# jQuery form submit handler doesn't trigger when textField changes by Watin in MVC Asp.net app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, watin

I am writing Watin test in MVC Asp.net app. I mvc app, all input are wrpped with form and every time an input or textarea is changed their form gets submitted by jquery like code below:

```
$("textarea", context).change(function() {
      $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
  });
```

This is perfect when changes are done by keyboard. However this doesn't trigger the form submit when input/textarea are changed by Watin TypeText() method. I tried to call Change() and Blur() events by Watin and also tried PressTab() with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Behnam Divsalar

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this bug in WatiN with the "onchange" event. A workaround is to trigger the event yourself.

```
Browser.Eval("$('textarea').change()");
```